# AsyncSSH saving output to list in Python

Tags: python, ssh

I'm trying to use AsyncSSH module to execute a command and capture the output for further processing. I was following the examples on the [official documentation](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#client-examples) but they all print() the result, I want to save it as a list. How would I do that in Python 3.5? I tried to modify the class by adding getdata() that would return 'out' list but it doesn't seem to be working

```
import asyncio, asyncssh, sys


class MySSHClientSession(asyncssh.SSHClientSession):

    out = []

    def data_received(self, data, datatype):
        if datatype == asyncssh.EXTENDED_DATA_STDERR:
            print(data, end='', file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            #print(data, end='')
            self.out.append(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        if exc:
            print('SSH session error: ' + str(exc), file=sys.stderr)

    def getdata(self):
        return self.out


async def run_client(zone, cmd):
    async with asyncssh.connect(zone, password='xxx', username='xxx', known_hosts=None) as conn:
        chan, session = await conn.create_session(MySSHClientSession, cmd)
        await chan.wait_closed()

try:
    x = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_client('fetish', 'sudo fl-service status'))
# the code to process x would go here
    print(x.getdata())
except (OSError, asyncssh.Error) as exc:
    sys.exit('SSH connection failed: ' + str(exc))
```

Comment: Did you find a way?

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code.

- your out[] wasn't initiated, you tried to append to None
- self.out can be used in its lifecycle only.

```
import asyncio, asyncssh, sys
    
class MySSHClientSession(asyncssh.SSHClientSession):
    def __init__(self):
        self.out = []

    def data_received(self, data, datatype):
        if datatype == asyncssh.EXTENDED_DATA_STDERR:
            print(data, end='', file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            #print(data, end='')
            self.out.append(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        if exc:
            print('SSH session error: ' + str(exc), file=sys.stderr)
        else:
            print(self.out)


async def run_client(zone, cmd):
    async with asyncssh.connect(zone, password='xxx', username='xxx', known_hosts=None) as conn:
        chan, session = await conn.create_session(MySSHClientSession, cmd)
        await chan.wait_closed()

try:
    x = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_client('fetish', 'whoami'))
# the code to process x would go here
    #print(x.getdata())
except (OSError, asyncssh.Error) as exc:
    sys.exit('SSH connection failed: ' + str(exc))
```